# Strapi query for relation with IN filter and AND clause

Tags: strapi

I have a collection `blogs` that has&belongs to many `categories` which have a `title` field.

I want to query `blogs` for results that have at least two specific category titles: `foo` and `bar`.

my blogs has the following entries:

- 2 entry with 0 categories
- 1 entry with 1 category: foo
- 1 entry with 2 categories: foo, bar

I've tried:

```
GET /blogs?_where[0][categories.title_in]=foo&_where[1][categories.title_in]=bar
```

--> 0 results

```
GET /blogs?[categories.title_in]=foo&[categories.title_in]=bar
```

--> 2 results

```
GET /blogs?[categories.title_in][0]=foo&[categories.title_in][1]=bar
```

--> 2 results

Basically I cannot get the `AND` condition to take. Filtering for both having `foo` AND `bar` categories should return only 1 result (the last one in the example)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seem to work for me in Strapi v4

multiple AND Filter

```
localhost:1337/api/artworks?publicationState=live&sort[0]=name&fields[0]=name&fields[1]=slug&fields[2]=price&fields[3]=width&fields[4]=height&populate[0]=image&populate[1]=artist&populate[2]=artwork_art_type&populate[3]=artwork_format&populate[4]=artwork_subject&populate[5]=artwork_technique&pagination[page]=&pagination[pageSize]=40&filters[$and][0][artwork_art_type][name][$eq]=${artworkArtTypeValue}&filters[$and][0][artwork_format][name][$eq]=${artworkFormatValue}
```

IN filter display all except with current ID

```
/artworks?publicationState=live&populate[0]=image&filters[artist][id][$eq]=${artworkArtistId}&filters[id][$ne]=${artworkId}&pagination[pageSize]=100
```

Comment: I get 500 error [2023-08-04 09:57:28.559] error: Only $and, $or and $not can only be used as root level operators. Found $eq.
Error: Only $and, $or and $not can only be used as root level operators. Found $eq.